# Using subqueries in Postgres SQL

Tags: postgresql

My data looks like this:

```
Name Status     Sub status      End Date
AAA  Active     High            N/A
AAA  Inactive   Intermediate    12/1/17
BBB  Inactive   High            12/31/17
BBB  Inactive   Intermediate    12/1/17
BBB  Inactive   Low             12/14/17
CCC  Inactive   Intermediate    9/11/17
CCC  Inactive   Low             9/21/17
DDD  Inactive   Intermediate    10/12/17
DDD  Inactive   Low             2/2/18
DDD  Inactive   Intermediate    9/21/17
DDD  Inactive   High            11/21/17
EEE  Inactive   Intermediate    8/2/17
EEE  Inactive   High            3/1/18
EEE  Active     Low             N/A
```

Output:

```
Name    Status      Sub status  End Date
BBB     Inactive    High        12/31/17
CCC     Inactive    Low         9/21/17
DDD     Inactive    Low         2/2/18
```

Explanation:

I need to look

1- Eliminate the ones that are Active status.
2- If not active, select distinct name and sub status of the person whose end date is the max of all their end dates

I tried using subquery to eliminate the ones that are in their "Active" status but does not work as expected. What else should I use to achieve my desired output!

PS: I use postgres SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> with x as
> (
>     select Name, max(EndDate) MaxEndDate
>     from   tbl t1
>     where  not exists (select 1
>                    from   tbl t2
>                    where  t2.Name = t1.Name
>                    and    t2.Status = 'Active')
>     group by Name
> )
> select t1.Name, t1.Status, t1.SubStatus, t1.EndDate
> from   tbl t1
> join   x
> on     t1.Name = x.Name
> and    t1.EndDate = x.MaxEndDate
> ```
>
> ```
> name | status   | substatus | enddate   
> :--- | :------- | :-------- | :---------
> BBB  | Inactive | High      | 2017-12-31
> CCC  | Inactive | Low       | 2017-09-21
> DDD  | Inactive | Low       | 2018-02-02
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=39371840e58b9e61c446beb95368f735)*

Answer (score 0):

```
 select name, status, sub_status,end_date
 where status='Inactive'
 group by name
 having end_date = max(end_date)
```

Basically you're eliminating the active records, then grouping by name and only getting the record for the greatest end date of each set. You may need to expand upon this if any end_date is null or you have any records with equal names and end dates.